# How to solve race condition in etcd leader election?

Tags: race-condition, coreos, etcd

While testing a Core Os cluster with three nodes, after successfully adding and removing few additional nodes, I encountered the following problem, supposedly due to a race condition during the election process for etcd.

Checking the new leader gives:

```
$ curl -L http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/stats/leader
{"errorCode":300,"message":"Raft Internal Error","index":629006}
```

Journalctl for each machine in the cluster gives:

```
$ journalctl -r -u etcd
-- Logs begin at Wed 2014-11-12 15:09:01 UTC, end at Mon 2014-11-24 10:47:34 UTC. --
Nov 24 10:47:34 node-1 etcd[56576]: [etcd] Nov 24 10:47:34.307 INFO      | 965d12d38a4a4b2c807bd232fb7b0db7: term #5221 started.
Nov 24 10:47:34 node-1 etcd[56576]: [etcd] Nov 24 10:47:34.306 INFO      | 965d12d38a4a4b2c807bd232fb7b0db7: state changed from 'candidate' to 'follower'.
Nov 24 10:47:33 node-1 etcd[56576]: [etcd] Nov 24 10:47:33.098 INFO      | 965d12d38a4a4b2c807bd232fb7b0db7: state changed from 'follower' to 'candidate'.
Nov 24 10:47:32 node-1 etcd[56576]: [etcd] Nov 24 10:47:32.081 INFO      | 965d12d38a4a4b2c807bd232fb7b0db7: term #5219 started.
Nov 24 10:47:32 node-1 etcd[56576]: [etcd] Nov 24 10:47:32.081 INFO      | 965d12d38a4a4b2c807bd232fb7b0db7: state changed from 'candidate' to 'follower'.
Nov 24 10:47:31 node-1 etcd[56576]: [etcd] Nov 24 10:47:31.962 INFO      | 965d12d38a4a4b2c807bd232fb7b0db7: state changed from 'follower' to 'candidate'.
```

And listing the machines with fleet fails:

```
$ fleetctl list-machines
2014/11/24 10:56:19 INFO client.go:278: Failed getting response from http://127.0.0.1:4001/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connection refused
2014/11/24 10:56:19 ERROR client.go:200: Unable to get result for {Get /_coreos.com/fleet/machines}, retrying in 100ms
2014/11/24 10:56:19 INFO client.go:278: Failed getting response from http://127.0.0.1:4001/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connection refused
2014/11/24 10:56:19 ERROR client.go:200: Unable to get result for {Get /_coreos.com/fleet/machines}, retrying in 200ms
2014/11/24 10:56:19 INFO client.go:278: Failed getting response from http://127.0.0.1:4001/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connection refused
```

Listing the machines in the cluster gives:

```
$ curl -L http://127.0.0.1:7001/v2/admin/machines
[{"name":"","state":"follower","clientURL":"http://100.72.62.35:4001","peerURL":"http://100.72.62.35:7001"},
{"name":"555cca74216644fea48990673b3d539c","state":"follower","clientURL":"http://100.72.62.59:4001","peerURL":"http://100.72.62.59:7001"},
{"name":"965d12d38a4a4b2c807bd232fb7b0db7","state":"follower","clientURL":"http://100.72.20.153:4001","peerURL":"http://100.72.20.153:7001"},
{"name":"a1b566dedb194c259f7eb2ffde5595b1","state":"follower","clientURL":"http://100.72.62.2:4001","peerURL":"http://100.72.62.2:7001"},
{"name":"a45efba827754b5f93c38b751a0ae273","state":"follower","clientURL":"http://100.72.62.31:4001","peerURL":"http://100.72.62.31:7001"},
{"name":"d041738235a9483cb814d37ca7fa4b6d","state":"follower","clientURL":"http://100.72.20.18:4001","peerURL":"http://100.72.20.18:7001"}]
```

but only three machines are currently running. I tried to add additional machines to reach the quorum with no avail. 
I'm running the following version:

```
$ etcdctl -v  
etcdctl version 0.4.6
```

for which, as mentioned here https://coreos.com/docs/distributed-configuration/etcd-api/#cluster-config, the leader module to force a leader has been removed. The ugly part is that since there is no quorum I'm not able to remove from the list of machines the ones that are not currently running using for example:

```
$ curl -L -XDELETE http://127.0.0.1:7001/v2/admin/machines/2abbf47a9e644bc69652a986d796d7a6
```

which has no effect. Is there any way to save the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, you can save the cluster, but it isn't worth it.

The cluster is not accepting new machines because it needs a quorum to add new machines and there is not a quorum of existing machines. The same goes for removing machines and deleting keys.

If you can bring up enough machines listed as cluster members and have them successfully work as cluster members, you will have a quorum and save the cluster.

From what I can see, you have six machines listed as cluster members. You need to have at least four running for the existing cluster to operate.